# Unable to add profile info into firebase collection when signing up (vue | firebase)

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuejs2

I'm getting these two errors

**TypeError: firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.default.firestore(...).collections is not a function**

**Cannot read property 'user' of undefined**

when trying to add user profile data into firebase collections 'profiles' when signing up. Please help.

This is the template section of my 'EditProfile' page.

```
 <template>
  <div class="edit-profile">
      <section>
          <div class="column">
           <div class="header" style="font-weight:bold">
                  Profile Settings
             </div>
                <div>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      class="form-control"
                      placeholder="Full name"
                      v-model="profile.name"
                    />
                     <input
                      type="phone"
                      class="form-control"
                      placeholder="Phone"
                      v-model="profile.phone"
                    />
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      class="form-control"
                      placeholder="Billing Address"
                      v-model="profile.address"
                    />
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      class="form-control"
                      placeholder="Postcode"
                      v-model="profile.postcode"
                    />
                  <button                
                    @click="updateProfile"
                  >
                    Save changes
                  </button>
          </div>
            </div>
      </section>
  </div>
</template>
```

Here is my script for the above EditProfile page.I haven't really added the code for edit profile bcuz I'm still unaware on how to do that

```
<script>
import firebase from "firebase";
require("firebase/auth");
export default {
  name: "EditProfile",
  data() {
    return {   
      profile: {
        fullName: null,
        phone: null,
        address: null,
        postcode: null,
      },
    };
  },
  methods: {
    updateProfile() {},
  },
 
};
</script>
```

Here is the template for 'RegisterCustomer' page. Here I will be signing up new users.

```
<template>
  <div class="row">
    <transition type="text/x-template" id="register-customer">
      <div class="modal-mask">
        <div class="modal-wrapper">
          <div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <slot name="body">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-4 off-set">
                    <form>
                      <div @click="$emit('close')">
                        <span class="close">&#10006;</span>
                      </div>
                      <h3>Sign up</h3>
                      <br />
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          class="form-control"
                          placeholder="fullName"
                          v-model="fullName"
                        />
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                      <input
                          type="email"
                          class="form-control"
                          placeholder="Email"
                          v-model="email"
                        />
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                      <input
                          type="password"
                          class="form-control"
                          placeholder="Password"
                          v-model="password"
                          @keyup.enter="
                            onSubmit();
                            $emit('close');
                          "
                        />
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-footer">
                        <slot name="footer">
                          <button
                            class="btn btn-primary"
                            type="button"
                            @click.prevent="onSubmit"
                            @click="$emit('close')"
                          >
                            Sign up
                          </button>
                        </slot>
                      </div>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </slot>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div></transition
    >
  </div>
</template>
```

This is my sign up code in my RegisterCustomer page. I want to add user info into my profiles collection. For now I want to pass the fullName data into my profiles collection.

```
<script>
import firebase from "firebase";
import "firebase/auth";
export default {
  name: "RegisterCustomer",
  data: () => ({
    fullName: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
  }),
  methods: {
    async onSubmit() {
      try {
        var { user } = await firebase
          .auth()
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password)
          .then(() => {
            firebase
              .firestore()
              .collection("profiles")
              .doc(user.uid)
              .update({
                fullName: this.fullName,
              });
            console.log("Document successfully written.");
          })
          .then(() => {
            alert("Registration successful.");
            console.log(user.uid);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error.message);
          });

        // this.$router.push("/customer");
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("error occured", error.message);
        alert(error.message);
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please share the complete code? Where is Firebase initialized? Have you imported firestore?

Comment: Hi there. I apologize for not having posted the complete code. I have edited it by adding the complete code of my 'RegisterCustomer' and 'EditProfile' page. Please help as I'm kinda stuck with managing users in firebase.

Comment: Can you please add `import "firebase/firestore";` below `import "firebase/auth";` ?

Comment: Still no changes brother. Got these errors: firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.default.firestore(...).collections is not a function
RegisterCustomer.vue?21a2:114 Cannot read property 'user' of undefined

Comment: It is `collection` and not `collections`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I got that corrected but I'm still getting a few errors.  FirebaseError: The caller does not have permission.                                                 
Cannot read property 'uid' of undefined
RegisterCustomer.vue?21a2:115 Cannot read property 'user' of undefined

Comment: I'm actually using custom tokens for customer and admin. Do you think it has anything to do with it? I'm no good at writing security rules but I tried the following:            match /profiles/{uid} {
       allow write: if request.auth == null;
        allow read, write: if request.auth.token.admin == true
      allow read, write: if request.auth.token.customer == true
    }

Comment: Hello, I've answered the question and if it was helpful you can accept and upvote it else feel free to ask further questions. About the security rules issue, it'll be better to ask a separate question as it's not totally related with the original. But from what I can see from the rules, any authenticated user can write to any document.

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer. All I had to do was change .update() to .set() when creating the profiles collection in RegisterCustomer.

Here is the script for RegisterCustomer. Hope someone finds this useful.

```
<script>
import firebase from "firebase";
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/firestore";
export default {
  name: "RegisterCustomer",
  data: () => ({
    fullName: null,
    email: null,
    password: null,
    address: null,
    postcode: null,
  }),
  methods: {
    async onSubmit() {
      try {
        firebase
          .auth()
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password)
          .then((cred) => {
            return firebase
              .firestore()
              .collection("profiles")
              .doc(cred.user.uid)
              .set({
                email: this.email,
                fullName: this.fullName,
                address: this.address,
                postcode: this.postcode,
              })
              .then(() => {
                console.log("Document successfully written.");
              });
          })
          .then(() => {
            alert("Registration successful.");
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error.message);
          });

        this.$router.push("/customer");
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error", error.message);
        alert(error.message);
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the Firebase services you are importing along with the core Firebase App as shown:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/firestore';
```

If you don't import Firestore that way, it'll result in similar issue. Although it was a typo in your case, it's "collection".

The second error *Cannot read property 'user' of undefined*, is probably because you are trying to get user property from a Promise. Try refactoring your code like this:

```
async onSubmit() {
  try {
    const { user } = await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password)
    await firebase.firestore().collection("profiles")
              .doc(user.uid)
              .update({
                fullName: this.fullName,
              });
    console.log("Document successfully written.");
    alert("Registration successful.");
    console.log(user.uid);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error occured", error.message);
    alert(error.message);
  }
},
```

Comment: Hey thanks so much for your response. Guess I'm a bit late but I figured out the answer! I had to change .update() to .set() when adding new collection. That solved the problem. Once again, thank you. Also my user undefined error was from 'console.log(user.uid)' right below the alert.